# Add to an array at the end of a loop

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, loops

What I want at the end of this code is an array which keeps adding to give and array with all $id in one array.

At the moment the code does 15 in the array, then gets overwritten by the next 15 items. I want to be able to an array at the end of the code which has 30 items in the array.

My code below:

```
$idArray = array();

do {
$html = file_get_html($url);
parseItems($html, $dbh);
sleep_flush($chunks=1); // ADJUST LATER
}

while (!empty($html->find('span[class=load-more-message]', 0)));

$html->clear();
unset($html); 

// -------------------------------------------------

function parseItems($html, $dbh) {

foreach($html->find('div.product-stamp-inner') as $content) {

$detail['itemid'] = filter_var($content->find('a.product-title-link', 0)->href, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$id = $detail['itemid'];
$idArray[] = $id; //Counting and adding items to an array

$detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
$description = $detail['title'];

if (!tableExists($dbh, $id, $detail)) {
    echo $id . " > " . $description .  "> Table does not exist >";
    createTable($dbh, $id, $description);
    insertData($dbh, $id, $detail);
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    echo $id . " > " . $description . "> Table already exists >";
    checkData($dbh, $id, $detail);
    echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    print_r($idArray);
}
```

Comment: Pull your `$idArray` out of the function definition to make it a global/session variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, because you redefine your $idArray here:

```
$idArray = array();
```

You could either make your $idArray global/member variable of the class.. or you can pass the parameter by reference:

```
$idArray = array();

do {
$html = file_get_html($url);
parseItems($html, $dbh, $idArray);
sleep_flush($chunks=1); // ADJUST LATER
}

while (!empty($html->find('span[class=load-more-message]', 0)));

$html->clear();
unset($html); 

// -------------------------------------------------

function parseItems($html, $dbh, &$idArray) {

foreach($html->find('div.product-stamp-inner') as $content) {

$detail['itemid'] = filter_var($content->find('a.product-title-link', 0)->href, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
$id = $detail['itemid'];
$idArray[] = $id; //Counting and adding items to an array

$detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
$description = $detail['title'];

if (!tableExists($dbh, $id, $detail)) {
    echo $id . " > " . $description .  "> Table does not exist >";
    createTable($dbh, $id, $description);
    insertData($dbh, $id, $detail);
    echo "<br>";
} else {
    echo $id . " > " . $description . "> Table already exists >";
    checkData($dbh, $id, $detail);
    echo "<br>";
        }
    }
    print_r($idArray);
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion still getting the array: `Array ( [0] => 363741 [1] => 367509 [2] => 915615 [3] => 744035 [4] => 910384 [5] => 771699 [6] => 742662 [7] => 338142 [8] => 139431 [9] => 350215 [10] => 757700 [11] => 377010 [12] => 363763 [13] => 326880 [14] => 903301 ) ` and `Array ( [0] => 771733 [1] => 771713 [2] => 710078 [3] => 710056 [4] => 710105 [5] => 773022 [6] => 271594 [7] => 323003 [8] => 917420 [9] => 910406 [10] => 65580 [11] => 19474 [12] => 908886 [13] => 64737 [14] => 306117 ) ` after the next loop. Still isn't adding them together

Comment: I recommend the first example here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php
It should clarify the solution I provided..
Be sure to add the & before your parameter in your function. And REMOVE the "$idArray = array();" in your loop.
If it's still 15 indexes, it's also possible, that your while clause "while (!empty($html->find('span[class=load-more-message]', 0)));" only matches once.